# Odoo 14 : element '<xpath expr="//*[hasclass('o_footer_copyright_name')]">' cannot be located in the parent view

Tags: templates, web, odoo, footer, odoo-website

I migrate from odoo 13 to odoo 14, but when I import all this; My website has an error like :

```
load could not load template
ValueError: The element '<xpath expr="//*[hasclass('o_footer_copyright_name')]">' could not be located in the parent view

View name: Footer Language Selector
Error context:
 view: ir.ui.view(3822,)
 view.parent: ir.ui.view(2094,)

Template: 1816
Path: /t/t
An error occurred while rendering template 1816
```

I didn't edited this view btw.

If anyone has a solution I'm interested!

Thanks by advance !

Comment: Any custom modules in this repo or do you migrating only data or code?

Comment: Hello @Saumilgauswami, thanks for your answer, there are no custom modules that work with this.

Comment: Sorry but one more question do you migrating db , because I want to know further.

Comment: no problem ! yes i did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced the same issue while upgrading from Odoo Enterprise 13 to 14.

Note the following points:

- The Release Notes (https://www.odoo.com/odoo-14-release-notes) state:
  "Add the language selector in the header and customize the layout."
- There is a new view added called 'Footer Language Selector' (Key:
  portal.footer_language_selector).  This appears to be added while
  running the Odoo DB upgrade 13 > 14.
- The 'Footer Language Selector' view is *not* created when setting up a new
  Odoo 14 database!

To resolve your issue, you need to disable the 'Footer Language Selector' view.  This can be done in one of two ways:

1. If you are logged in to your Odoo instance, enable Developer Mode, and go to Settings > Technical > User Interface > Views and search for 'Footer Language Selector'.  Select the view, and then select the menu option to 'Archive'
2. If you are not logged in/not able to log in, you need to disable the view in the database directly.  Here is the command that will disable the view: `UPDATE public.ir_ui_view SET active = false WHERE id = 3822;` **NOTE:**  the 'id = **3822**' value must match the view number in the error: `ir.ui.view(3822,)`

I hope this helps you resolve the issue which appears to be a bug introduced by the Odoo DB update tool.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's probably due to that, solution 1 is what I did! So that makes me feel more confident that I'm right to have done that.
I created a ticket at Odoo directly, here is what they say: 

In the standard Footer Language Selector view, it has a parent view whose own parent view contains the o_footer_copyright_name class.

The standard view that contains it is called Frontend Layout (id 192) and the view on your site has 484. Try add the missing class to the line :

 <span class="o_footer_copyright_name" t-field="res_company.name" itemprop="name">Company name</span>

Comment: Thanks for sharing the response from Odoo.  I don't understand where Odoo are suggesting that the class is added - I cannot see the o_footer_copyright_name class the common v14 OCA themes online.  If you have any further suggestions on this point it would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: i did the first solution and it worked! thank you @BeechCoder!